# trying to print data grid view ,It's being left to right

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I'm trying to print data grid view in c# using this class
the problem is when i print it, the data grid columns being reflected (left to right ) i need it being as in the design (right to left)

I used this method
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16670/DataGridView-Printing-by-Selecting-Columns-and-Row

Comment: That code is terrifying. Try this other: [DGVPrinter - GitHub](https://github.com/vijaythapa333/DGVPrinter/blob/master/DGVPrinter.cs) -- Not tested, but it looks quite better.

Comment: What font are you using?  Are cell alligned left or right?  Search you link for "cell".  I suspect you are getting the text from the cell which is loosing the cell format.